# cakephp - a different has many through relationship

Tags: cakephp, relationship

I was wondering if this is possible to do with a has many through

```
contents       orgs            folders
 id             id              id
 name           name            title
 link

join table - folder_elements
              id
              element_id
              order
```

contents has many folders through folder_elements

orgs has many folders through folder_elements

So my question is, is it possible to use element_id to store the content.id or the org.id ?

Alex

Comment: `folder_elements` will break cake conventions, so its its highly NOT recommended, watch Daniel proposed solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is a sort of HABTM (HasAndBelongsToMany) association. You could define the inter-model associations as you suggest, but there's a pretty significant design flaw: how would you account for a situation where the same ID is used for an `orgs` record and a `contents` record, and wish to associate them with the same `folder` record? It would be impossible to differentiate between the two in your joining table.

There are a number of ways to work around this, but they require more program logic or a more disorganised database schema that presents challenges in maintainability.

The more elegant, robust solution is to rationalise your database structure. If there's no *pressing need* to have One Join Table to Rule Them All, you could design your model associations like this:

- `Content hasMany ContentsFolder belongsTo Folder`
- `Folder hasMany ContentsFolder belongsTo Content`
- `Org hasMany OrgsFolder belongsTo Folder`
- `Folder hasMany OrgsFolder belongsTo Org`

This is the internal structure of a HABTM association defined explicitly so you can define fields in the joining table. Your `contents` and `folders` tables would remain the same, but your two joining tables would look like:

```
contents_folders
-> id
-> content_id
-> order

orgs_folders
-> id
-> org_id
-> order
```

Unfortunately, yes, this would require defining five models instead of three, but such are the limitations of CakePHP's object-relational modelling.